# Java 2D-Graphics : Animate Fractal tree

Tags: java, swing, animation, tree, thread-sleep

I'm trying to draw a fractal tree.

It will draw the tree, but i want to make an animation so the tree can grow from its "trunk"? Also is it possible to make that animation smooth?

If i use Thread.sleep method, it draws the tree pretty weird.

Someone who can help me? Many thanks

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FractalTree extends Canvas {

      private JFrame frame;

      //Breedte en hoogte voor GUI
      private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280;
      private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720;

      public FractalTree() {
        frame = new JFrame("Fractal Tree");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        FractalTree ft = new FractalTree();
        ft.setVisible(true);
        ft.setBackground(Color.black);
      }


class FractalPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private int x;
private int y;
private int xNew;
private int yNew;
private double angle;
private int depth;

public FractalPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.black);
    Timer timer = new Timer(200, this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    drawFractalTree(g, WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 75, -90, 11);
  }

  public void drawFractalTree(Graphics g, int x, int y, double angle, int depth) {

    if (depth == 0) {
    } else {

      int xNew = x + (int) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0);
      int yNew = y + (int) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0);

      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f * depth));
      g2d.drawLine(x, y, xNew, yNew);

      drawFractalTree(g, xNew, yNew, angle + 30, depth - 1);
      drawFractalTree(g, xNew, yNew, angle - 30, depth - 1);
    }
  }


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (depth == 0) {
    } else {

      int xNew = x + (int) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0);
      int yNew = y + (int) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0);
      repaint();
    }

}
```

}
}

PS: Sorry about my English

Answer (score 4):

Don't mix swing and awt (`Canvas` and `JFrame`). Instead of using canvas you can extends JPanel and override `paintComponent(Grahics g)` method where you can do all your drawings.

Don't call `Thread.sleep(10);` in paint. It just blocks Event Dispatcher Thread and prevents painting.

Instead create a `Timer` to be called each desired time interval. In the Timer's action change the model (x, y etc) and call `repaint()` to reflect the changes.

Comment: I have now something like this

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (depth == 0) {
     } else {
      
       int xNew = x + (int) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0);
       int yNew = y + (int) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0);
       repaint();
     }
  
 }

Sorry but how can I use the Timer to make it work? Im a newbie with this, ive edited my post

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html here is an example. In fact you define interval, action to be done and start the timer. the actionPerformed is called in the time interval.